# Process Automation SuperBadge Step 5 - How to properly validate when opportunity is Negotiation/Review

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Im having a problem validatin a step in the Process Automation Specialist!

This are the tasks that they ask to accomplish:

[image]

[image]

But I did created this step in my process:

[image]

The Opp fields being validated are Opp.Stage and Opp.Amount in the rows above.

Any idea how this can be accomplished ?

Answer (score 3):

First change your criteria from **equals** $100,000 to **greater than** $100,00.

If the error persists it could just simply be not telling your process to evaluate the next step:
[screen shot of evaluate next criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwt2q.png).

Answer (score 0):

If you add "Evaluate the Next Criteria" it will work!